# Application defined or object defined error: VBA: sumifs formula

Tags: vba, sumifs

I am not able to correct this code. It is throwing error in line where i have used sumifs formula. Whats wrong in this?

```
Sub try()   
Dim Arg1 As Range   
Dim Arg2 As Range   
Dim Arg3 As Range   
Dim Arg4 As Range   



Set Arg1 = Sheets("Raw Data_All Products").Range("O:O")   
Set Arg2 = Sheets("Raw Data_All Products").Range("J:J")   
Set Arg3 = Sheets("Raw Data_All Products").Range("B:B")   
Set Arg4 = Sheets("Raw Data_All Products").Range("A:A")   

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, c).Value = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, "SM Parcels", Arg3, "2015", 
Arg4, "1")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> Issue line: Sheets("Sheet2").**Cells(12, c)**.Value =

You have a syntax issue with the `Cells` object. The correct syntax is `Cells(Row Index, Col Index)` where index is a number (or col letter houesd in quotes).

**Row Index** is self explanatory (`1 = 1`).
**Column Index**: `A = 1`, `B = 2`, `C = 3` or `A = "A"`, `B = "B"`, `C = "C"`

---

If your goal is to have the `SUMIF` value displayed in cell `C12`, you can try any of the three equal alternatives below.

```
1) Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, "C").Value =
2) Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(12, 3).Value =
3) Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C12").Value =
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped.